# How to set force_col_wise=True in LGBClassifier Scikit-Learn API with cross_validate

Tags: scikit-learn, lightgbm

I am using LGBMClassifier Scikit-Learn API with `cross_validate`. I want to set `force_col_wise=True` because auto-choosing takes a lot of time.

```
Auto-choosing col-wise multi-threading, the overhead of testing was 47.296749 seconds.
You can set `force_col_wise=true` to remove the overhead.
```

but I could not find anything related to it in docs. How to do it?

https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html

Comment: could you add a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Try including this in your params list:
'force_col_wise': 'true'

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in the constructor:
`LGBMClassifier(force_col_wise=True)`.

Comment: Upvoted because this is the correct answer, and is documented here: https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#force_col_wise